# Change a variable to value on different sheet

Tags: google-apps-script

Please help me, how can I change this variable to a cell on a different sheet.

```
var recipients = "myemail@address.com"
```

I've tried and failed many times.

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

Here the code to get the value of a specific cell:

```
var recipients = SpreadsheetApp.openById("SPREADSHEET_ID").getSheetByName("SHEET_NAME").getRange("row_nb", "column_nb", 1, 1).getValue()
```